# datepicker angular2 in dart not reading selected date

Tags: angular, datepicker, dart

I am kind of a new angular2 programmer I try to use datepicker.
add text input type :

```html
<input type='text [datepicker]="selectedDate"></input>
```

inside a form I included `import 'package:ng_bootstrap/ng_bootstrap.dart';`

file.html:

```html
<form (submit)="onSubmit(myForm.value)">
</form>
```

component.dart

```dart
onSubmit(value){
  print(selectedDate);
}
```

Why doesn't it get the value I selected in the datepicker?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Could you please show the example in dartpad or some other online editor? It'd be easier to reproduce. Also, could you paste more code? It's hard to guess what's missing.